# How to get the middle character from a string with the right answer?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

After some tries only one of this fonction gave me the right result in CodeWars.
Can any one explain to me the reason please?

```
{
  //1. solution => wrong
  var middle = Math.round(s.length / 2); 
  s.length % 2 == 0 ? console.log(s[middle-1] + s[middle]) : console.log(s[middle-1]);

 //2. solution => correct
return (s.length%2 == 0 ? s.substr((s.length/2-1),2) : s.substr((s.length/2),1));
}
```

and the result to solution 1 is:
[image]

Comment: The first solution doesn't return anything? Try returning the values, and not using console.log?

Comment: Please stat clearly the problem you are trying to solve, give the input and the expected output and show what the wrong solution produces instead

Answer (score 0):

The first solution handles strings with an odd length incorrectly; it is returning the character *before* the middle `s[middle-1]` instead of the character in the middle `s[middle]` .

The second solution fixes that by getting the character at position `(s.length/2)`, which corresponds to the value of middle in the first solution.

Update with additional issue from @evolutionxbox:

As @evolutionxbox pointed out, if your original solution was using console.log instead of return to output the results, that is also an issue.  I assumed that you added that to view the results side by side.

Comment: This isn't the only issue/difference between the two

Comment: I assumed that he added the console.log to compare the two solutions side by side (to log the values from his old solution against the correct values from the new one to identify the differences).  If that isn't intentional, that would cause an even bigger issue. :)

Comment: @JohnGlenn if that would be the case, then the failed tests messages would not say `expected undefined to equal 'es'`. If the 1st solution has been returning values at any point in time, those test would have passed. The 1st solution calculates the same results as the 2nd solution. The only difference is that the 1st solution has never returned the results, thus the 'undefined' in the test failed messages.

Comment: @Ma3x - Do they return the same solution for odd lengthed strings?

Comment: @JohnGlenn they do, the only difference is on an empty string.

Comment: @Ma3x - So is s[Math.round(s.length / 2) -1] (result for an odd string from the first)  ((note the minus one)) the same as s[(s.length / 2)] from the second (note the lack of a minus one)?

Comment: @JohnGlenn The examples that you provide here in the comments of course wont produce the same value, but you need to keep in mind that the 2nd solution is passing the divided value to the .substr() call, which will happily accept non-integer values as well. And for 1st solution using `Math.round(s.length / 2) -1` is okay, because for odd length it will be rounded upwards, so -1 is then required. But I do agree, that it could have been done in a different and more readable way. It does not make it wrong though (debatable for the empty string input).

Comment: Than you every one, for every detail and explanation. Just to clarify, @JohnGleen you have assumed it correctly (about my console.log), and Ma3x, you are also right saying about the empty string...i didn't think in that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

The failed test(s) messages tell you that the returned value (the value received by the test code) was always `undefined`, since they state `expected undefined to equal 'es'`.

The problem with your 1st solution is that it prints the results to the console (by calling `console.log`) instead of returning the result with a `return` statement.

If you get rid of `console.log` calls and add a `return` statement, then the 1st solution is almost identical to the 2nd solution and it will pass most tests.

There is still a slight difference though, the 1st solution returns `NaN` if the input is an empty string, while the 2nd solution returns an empty string. So depending on the tests suite, the 1st solution might still not pass all the tests.

Run the code below to compare the results.

```js
solution1 = (s) => {
  var middle = Math.round(s.length / 2);
  return s.length % 2 == 0 ? s[middle-1]+s[middle] : s[middle-1];
};

solution2 = (s) => {
  return (s.length%2 == 0 ? s.substr((s.length/2-1),2) : s.substr((s.length/2),1));
};

["", "x", "oz", "eye", "test", "--z--", "---uv---"].forEach(it =>
  console.log("solution1: '%s' solution2: '%s' for input '%s'", solution1(it), solution2(it), it)
);
```